# Xamarin.Forms using generic types as a type argument in XAML

Tags: xaml, generics, xamarin.forms

I have a custom control:

```
public class CustomControl<T> : ContentView
{

}
```

I can create an instance of this custom control with the type argument TimeSpan in XAML in Xamarin.Forms with the following:

```
<controls:CustomControl x:TypeArguments="x:TimeSpan" />
```

How can I assign the type argument as Nullable<TimeSpan> so that I have an instance of CustomControl<Nullable<TimeSpan>>? I have tried the following:

```
<controls:CustomControl x:TypeArguments="x:Nullable<TimeSpan>" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in codebehind with code like:

```
CustomControl<TimeSpan?> customscontrol=new CustomControl<TimeSpan?>();
```

Comment: Thanks Adrain, that is a helpful suggestion. But is there no way that this can be done in XAML? I'm assuming it's supported and I just can't find the correct syntax.

Comment: I can't find any document about this , you can check xamarin generics https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/generics

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. I have read through the docs too and couldn't find what I was after. I may end up doing as you have suggested.